# What is the purpose of a route name in mojolicious?

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious

I have been learning how to program apps using the Mojolicious framework and I am stumped as to why you use route names. For example a route could say

```
$r->route('/cities/new')
      ->via('get')
      ->to(controller => 'cities', action => 'new_form')
      ->name('cities_new_form');
```

But what is the purpose of the name parameter? I am new to web frameworks, so maybe this has a trivial answer to it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Naming the route allows you to reference it later if you want to generate a URL dynamically. With your example, you could do this later in your code:

```
my $link = $self->url_for( 'cities_new_form' )
```

and `$link` would automatically be populated with a URL ending in `/cities/new`. You can get fancy if your route has dynamic parts. For example:

```
$r->route( '/cities/:cityname' )
    ->via( 'get' )
    ->to( controller => 'cities', action => 'new_form' )
    ->name( 'cities_new_form' );
```

Then you can generate a URL like

```
my $link = $self->url_for( 'cities_new_form', cityname => 'newyork' );
```

And `$link` would end up with `/cities/newyork`.

These are trivial examples, but you can build up fairly complex stuff once your routes get more involved.

If you don't name the route, it gets a default name which is just a concatenation of the alphanumeric characters in it. That can get tedious for long routes so you can use names to abbreviate them.

See also [Named Routes](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Named_routes) in the Mojolicious documentation.